# How get table for such error - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm doing migration from Magento 1.9 to 2.1. And I get the following error

```
[PDOException]                                                                                                                               
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '460-13326' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'
```

How can I find which MySQL table relate to this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity did you understand the question? Why is it not about programming? A database is a part of development and database error handling as well.

Comment: A computer is part of development too but asking a general computer question is not about programming. Asking a general database question, similarly, is not necessarily about programming.

Comment: @Enigmativity please give me answer and I'll remove this question if this important for you.

Comment: I have the same issue trying to migrate orders and customers to a site where the tool has run once before using the --reset option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a relationship inside the table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`